# Eikonal Approximation from weinberg book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, scattering

In weinberg's book, the author has calculated the power series of$$
H(\nabla S(\mathbf{x})-i \hbar \nabla, \mathbf{x}) N(\mathbf{x})=E N(\mathbf{x}) .
$$
and mentioned that the function $H(\nabla S(\mathbf{x})-i \hbar \nabla, \mathbf{x})$ is defined by its power-series expansion. In this expansion, it should be understood that the operator $-i \hbar \nabla$ acts on everything to its right, including not only $N$ but also the derivatives of $S$.
Then the above equation satisfied, the terms of zeroth order in the gradients of $N(\mathbf{x})$ and $\nabla S(\mathbf{x})$ cancel. To first order in these gradients, the Schrödinger equation then becomes
$$
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \nabla N(\mathbf{x})+B(\mathbf{x}) N(\mathbf{x})=0,
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
A_i(\mathbf{x}) & \equiv\left[\frac{\partial H(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{x})}{\partial p_i}\right]_{\mathbf{p}=\nabla S(\mathbf{x})}, \\
B(\mathbf{x}) & \equiv \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i j}\left[\frac{\partial^2 H(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{x})}{\partial p_i \partial p_j}\right]_{\mathbf{p}=\nabla S(\mathbf{x})} \frac{\partial^2 S(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} .
\end{aligned}
$$
To get A(X) and B(X), I have proceeded as follows
$$
H(\nabla S) N+\left(-i \hbar \sum_i \nabla_i\right)\left[\left(\partial H / \partial p_i\right)_{p=\nabla S} N\right]=E N
$$

The zero-th order terms $H(\nabla S) N$ and $E N$ cancel, as per (7.10.3). The remaining $\nabla$ yields then
$$
\sum_i\left(\partial H / \partial p_i\right)_{p=\nabla S}\left(\nabla_i N\right)+N \sum_{i j}\left(\partial p_j / \partial x_i\right)_{p=\nabla S} \partial / \partial p_j\left(\partial H / \partial p_i\right)_{p=\nabla S}=0,
$$
i.e.,
$$A . \nabla(N)+N  \sum_{i j}\left(\partial^2 S / \partial x_j \partial x_i\right)\left(\partial^2 H / \partial p_j \partial p_i\right)_{p=\nabla S}=A . \nabla(N)+N B=0$$
However the factor of 1/2 is missing from my calculation. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Lectures on Quantum Mechanics, Second Edition by steven Weinberg, page 276-277